# Run script multiple times using variable in constraint

Tags: sql, variables, loops, where-clause

[image: table]

Is there a way of populating the Cust1, Cust2, Cust3 columns in Table2 that doesn't involve running the same query with several different "WHERE" clauses?

For example, right now I would resort to doing this:

```
INSERT INTO Table2(Cust1_Totals)
SELECT Fruit, SUM(quantity)
FROM Table1
WHERE Customer_ID LIKE 1
GROUP BY Fruit

INSERT INTO Table2(Cust2_Totals)
SELECT Fruit, SUM(quantity)
FROM Table1
WHERE Customer_ID LIKE 2
GROUP BY Fruit

INSERT INTO Table2(Cust3_Totals)
SELECT Fruit, SUM(quantity)
FROM Table1
WHERE Customer_ID LIKE 3
GROUP BY Fruit
```

Ideally, I would like to have another table with a Customer_ID column of all the unique customers and then I would reference each one in a loop in the above query.  SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `case` to generate sums per customer in separate columns:

```
INSERT  Table2
        (Produce, Cust1_Totals, Cust2_Totals, Cust3_Totals)
SELECT  Fruit
,       SUM(case when Customer_ID = 1 then quantity end)
,       SUM(case when Customer_ID = 2 then quantity end)
,       SUM(case when Customer_ID = 3 then quantity end)
FROM    Table1
WHERE   Customer_ID IN (1,2,3)
GROUP BY 
        Fruit
```

Generating a variable numbers of columns  would require dynamic sql.  It's usually easier to let Excel that.  In Excel-speak, it's known as "pivoting".

Comment: This seems like a good idea, but I am worried about instances where I will have about 10 sets of columns per "customer" to populate.  This would lead to a lot of lengthy statements.  Would things be different if I had a fixed # of customers in another table?  I don't really need this to be dynamic.  I just want it to run for each customer in the other table.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
select * from table1
pivot (sum(quantity) for customerid in ([1], [2], [3])) as pivotTable
```

But you still have to specify the customer IDs here.